# Django localized date parsing

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I have a django application that is completly internationalized and we are using date fields that also should be in the format of the respective language. Now I've got the problem that I must parse different date formats based on the current language.

I've tried this:

```
from django.utils import formats, translation
format_code = formats.get_format("SHORT_DATE_FORMAT", lang=translation.get_language())
```

It returns the currently used date format (e.g. "d.m.Y" for Germany) but I need it in a date format I can parse with datetime.strptime (e.g. "%d.%m.%Y"). How can I get this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the best way I found is this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import formats

def parse_locale_date(formatted_date):
    parsed_date = None
    for date_format in formats.get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS'):
        try:
            parsed_date = datetime.strptime(formatted_date, date_format)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            break
    if not parsed_date:
        raise ValueError
    return parsed_date.date()
```

Answer (score 0):

see this from the documentation:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
<p>{% trans "your date here" %}</p>

{% language 'en' %}
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <!-- Current language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} -->
    <p>{% trans "your date format here" %}</p>
{% endlanguage %}
```

check out documentation here: [Switching language in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how this can solve my problem. I won't translate my date format. I search for an option to get the current dateformat to work with it with datetime.strftime.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `formats.date_format(value, format)` instead of `datetime.strptime`, for example:

```
from django.utils import formats, translation
format_code = formats.get_format("SHORT_DATE_FORMAT", lang=translation.get_language())
formats.date_format(your_date, format_code)
```